# How "steady" are screw threads?

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science

I have a setup whereby two stainless steel end caps screw into a similar tube about 100mm in length and 25mm internal diameter. Thread is fairly standard, and is finger tight.

The question is: Ignoring effects of direct thermal expansion on length how stable is the distance between the two end caps? I need 100nm stability...

Comment: How well did you isolate your setup from vibrations? I expect that both thermal expansion and vibration will be large when you want 100 nm stability. What is the frequency range of your "stability". Are you looking for kHz, or mHz? Is it an option to add a dab of Loctite to the threads? I think that on the whole the "100 mm stainless tube" is a bigger problem than the threads themselves. But I would most certainly add something to stop the threads from moving.

Comment: I will probably first measure it by cycling through (say) 50 degC and seeing whether the distances remain consistent. The time constant for the measurements is about a second. The length of the tube doesn't matter and is calibrated out.

Comment: You have interesting experimental setups...  You are looking for stability to one part in $10^{6}$, so thermal expansion will be an issue (1 degree will be several 100nm). Beyond that, I would go with micrometer screws, which have backlash reduction built in. Optics supply places like, say, Newport, have a variety of options designed for long-term stability.  Pricier than a standard extra-fine thread machine screw. One I quickly googled was 1 inch travel 1/4-80 thread, long-term stable for about $30/each.  Higher performance ones exist as well.

Comment: In aerospace applications one would use something like helicoil thread inserts. http://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/brands/heli-coil/screw-thread-inserts